# Check If String Contains All "?"

Tags: c#

How can I check if a string contains all question marks?  Like this:

string input = "????????";

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var isAllQuestionMarks = input.All(c => c == '?');
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use [Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx):

```
bool isAllQuestion = input.All(c => c=='?');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
        string = "????????";
        bool allQuestionMarks = input  == new string('?', input.Length);
```

Just ran a comparison:

this way is heaps x faster than the `input.All(c => c=='?');`

```
public static void Main() {
            Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
            string input = "????????";
            w.Start();
            bool allQuestionMarks;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
                allQuestionMarks = input == new string('?', input.Length);
            }
            w.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("String way {0}", w.ElapsedTicks);


            w.Reset();
            w.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                allQuestionMarks = input.All(c => c=='?');
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" Linq way {0}", w.ElapsedTicks);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

**String way 11
 Linq way 4189**

Comment: You're not testing cases where they are NOT equal - it's an unfair test.  You're only checking the worst case scenario for "All"

Comment: Please - I'm happy for you to correct it. Just make the test better and put the results in

Comment: @Reed, where do you see negative checking? "All" fails on first non-matching element.

Comment: @macias: Yes, but he's checking against a string where it will never fail early.  His test is always creating the "worst case" scenario for All.

Comment: @Reed, Preet (not "he") tests for string equality in case of match, which is also a worst case for string comparison.

Comment: @macias: True, but string comparison is optimized differently - different profiling semantics.

Answer (score 4):

So many linq answers! Can't we do anything the old-fashioned way any more?
 This is an order of magnitude faster than the linq solution. More readable? Maybe not, but that is what method names are for.

```
    static bool IsAllQuestionMarks(String s) {

        for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            if(s[i] != '?')
                return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bool allQuestionMarks = input.All(c => c == '?');
```

This uses [the LINQ `All` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx), which "determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition." In this case, the elements of the collection are characters, and the condition is that the character is equal to the question mark character.

Answer (score 3):

Not very readable... But a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) is another way to do it (and it's fast):

```
// Looking for a string composed only by one or more "?":
bool allQuestionMarks = Regex.IsMatch(input, "^\?+$");
```

Comment: Define fast, because I think this is no faster than the linq solution, but without the readability.

Comment: Definition: fast enough. I'm not comparing regex with linq, I'm just showing an alternative way. I'm not that sure linq is more readable though - or you're saying that linq, a functional-monadic-dsl, is easier to understand than a regular expression...? :-) To me they both share similar characteristics: easy to write, not that easy to understand after you wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

you could do it in linq...

```
bool result = input.ToCharArray().All(c => c=='?');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
private bool CheckIfStringContainsOnlyQuestionMark(string value)
{
    return !value.Where(a => a != '?').Select(a => true).FirstOrDefault();
}
```